# Does nifi supports Transfering single Flow file to multiple Relationships in a Processor?

Tags: minify, apache-nifi

I am exploring options for Transferring **single Flowfile to two or more Relationships in my custom processor**,i didn't found any help in documentation for this, **Does this feature supported by NIFI?**

Example Code:

```
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS_1);
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS_2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `session.clone()` method:

```
FlowFile flowFile2 = session.clone(flowFile);
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS_1);
session.transfer(flowFile2, REL_SUCCESS_2);
```

to create a full clone of the flow file.

the content and attributes will be the same...

Comment: Thanks for your answer daggett, i will try this approch